# Increasing the value of a nullable int (int?)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, integer, nullable

I'm using a nullable integer, and increasing that by one in the following way:

```
        item.addItem = function () {
                //Check if item is already in the table on the right
                if (viewModel.orderedItems.indexOf(this) < 0) {

                    if (isNaN(this.qty) || this.qty == 'undefined' || this.qty <= 0) {
                        //alert('is NaN1')

                        this.qty = 1;
                        //this.qty.value = 0;
                    }
                    //alert(this.qty.value);
                    viewModel.orderedItems.push(this);
                }
                else {
                    if (isNaN(this.qty) || this.qty == 'undefined' || this.qty <= 0) {
                        //alert('is NaN2')
                        this.qty + 1;
                        //this.qty.value = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        viewModel.orderedItems.remove(this);
                        this.qty = this.qty + 1;
                        viewModel.orderedItems.push(this);

                    }

                }`
```

Now, this qty shows in an inputfield, where you can change it.

Let's say, I wrote 15 as the quantity, and decided to 'click' to increase it by one, it results '151' (15 +1), instead of 16. 
How could I get it to actually increase by one, instead of adding a one?

Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can cast the type with `+this.qty + 1` as well, less readable though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by converting this string to number using [**parseInt**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) and add 1 to it

```
parseInt(this.qty,10) + 1;
```

where 10 is the radix

You can also use [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

Beside a widely use construct is using [**Unary_plus**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus) which attempts to convert it to number .

So in your case it will be

```
+this.qty + 1;
```

Comment: This works as well, thank you for your fast replies!

Comment: @user2181397: You don't really need to specify the radix for this example, right? It will auto-detect it as a decimal.

Comment: @niandrei I personally don't think so, however I'm adding the radix just to be safe.

Answer (score 3):

Replace :

```
this.qty + 1;
```

By

```
parseInt(this.qty) + 1;
```

But you have a problem because something change type of qty value.

Comment: Perfecto! (Can accept in 10 minutes)